# Minimum no of deletions/insertions to make string palindrome

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

When considering minimum number of deletions to make string palindrome, we use longest palindromic subsequence but when minimum number of insertions are asked we use longest common subsequence with reverse of string.

I'm unable to understand why is such difference.
Minimum number of insertions must be same as minimum number of deletions but not here. Can someone throw a light on it ?

thanks

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: LCS can be used for both tasks.

Answer (score 0):

function to make string palindrome with a minimum number of deletions

```
//User function template for C++

class Solution{
  public:
   
    int minimumNumberOfDeletions(string S) { 
        int n=S.size();
        int dp[n][n];
        memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
       
        
        
        for(int startcol=1;startcol<n;startcol++)
        {  int j=startcol;
            for(int row=0;j<n;row++)
            {
               
               if(S[row]==S[j]) dp[row][j]=dp[row+1][j-1];
                else
                {
                    dp[row][j]=min(dp[row][j-1],dp[row+1][j])+1;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
       
        return dp[0][n-1];
    } 
};
```